# Display html using a wxPython control

Tags: html, wxpython, rtf

I am trying to display rich text (or html) in a segment of a wx python frame

I have tried the rtf control with no luck (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864732/using-wxpython-rich-text-control)). I am now trying the html route, but in the only examples I can find the html is display in a window that takes over the whole frame; for example from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/AddhtmltoHtmlWindow.htm)

```
    import wx
import wx.html

class MyHtmlFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        html = wx.html.HtmlWindow(self)
        if "gtk2" in wx.PlatformInfo:
            html.SetStandardFonts()

        html.SetPage(
            "Here is some <b>formatted</b> <i><u>text</u></i> "
            "loaded from a <font color=\"red\">string</font>.")


app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frm = MyHtmlFrame(None, "Simple HTML")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Is it possible to display html in a textbox or some other suitable control that I can incorporate into my application?

I want the screen to look like that below. Can the wx.TextCtrl be replaced by an HTML window or something?

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        panel.txt_comments.SetValue(
                    "Here is some <b>formatted</b>"
                    "<i><u>text</u></i> "
                    "loaded from a "
                    "<font color=\"red\">string</font>.")

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)

        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE
        self.txt_comments = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(300, 150), style=txt_style)
        cmd_update = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_REFRESH)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(self.txt_comments, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        main_sizer.Add(cmd_update, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

app = wx.App()
frm = MainFrame(None, "Screen layout")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be somewhat close to an utter minimum of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.html as html

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
ID_New  = wx.NewId()
ID_Exit = wx.NewId()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyParentFrame(wx.MDIParentFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.MDIParentFrame.__init__(self, None, -1, "MDI Parent", size=(600,400))

        self.winCount = 0
        menu = wx.Menu()
        menu.Append(ID_New, "&New Window")
        menu.AppendSeparator()
        menu.Append(ID_Exit, "E&xit")

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(menu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnNewWindow, id=ID_New)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, id=ID_Exit)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close(True)

    def OnNewWindow(self, evt):
        self.winCount = self.winCount + 1
        win = wx.MDIChildFrame(self, -1, "Child Window: %d" % self.winCount)
        self.html = html.HtmlWindow(win, -1)
        self.html.SetPage(
            "Here is some <b>formatted</b> <i><u>text</u></i> "
            "loaded from a <font color=\"red\">string</font>.")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class MyApp(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
            frame = MyParentFrame()
            frame.Show(True)
            self.SetTopWindow(frame)
            return True

    app = MyApp(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

I expect the main lines to note are these:

```
    win = wx.MDIChildFrame(self, -1, "Child Window: %d" % self.winCount)
    self.html = html.HtmlWindow(win, -1)
    self.html.SetPage(
        "Here is some <b>formatted</b> <i><u>text</u></i> "
        "loaded from a <font color=\"red\">string</font>.")
```

- `win` is the frame in which you want to house the HTMLWindow.
- Notice that `win` is the first parameter to HTMLWindow.

I used wxWindow quite a bit several years ago, and I've lost most of my skills. Now I remember that the secret to getting a leg up is to start with the demo codes. I used a couple of them this time.

Edit on the basis of comments:

```
import wx
import wx.html as html

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        panel = MainPanel(self)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)

        txt_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE
        self.html = html.HtmlWindow(self, -1, size=(300, 150), style=txt_style)
        self.html.SetPage(
                    "Here is some <b>formatted</b>"
                    "<i><u>text</u></i> "
                    "loaded from a "
                    "<font color=\"red\">string</font>.")

app = wx.App()
frm = MainFrame(None, "Screen layout")
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, but I want a "control" that handles HTML, not the whole window. Is this possible? I have updated my question to include an example screen showing the layout

Comment: There must be something I'm still missing. If you run the code that appears under that 'example screen' you will get the 'example screen'.

Comment: Oh dear. Chinese whispers! I just want the html to appear where the txtCtrl appears, not the whole window

Comment: Perhaps you mean by 'control' that you want to make an object that can contain HTML and respond to clicks, etc? Then what I suggested above does that, in the sense that MDIChildFrame inherits from Frame. You can make a 'control' by putting an HTMLWindow in a Frame, or anything that inherits from Frame, as I did. If you want to see more about events then have a look at the demo for HTMLWindow.

Comment: As you say, Chinese whispers.

Comment: OK, you want to use an HTMLWindow (somehow) in place of a txtCtrl.

Comment: Exactly! That's what I want

Comment: Welcome! -------

Answer (score 2):

`wx.html.HtmlWindow` or `wx.html2.WebView` are much like other child widgets in wxPython, in that they need a parent, and the size and position need to be managed in some way, and so on. That also means that you can replace the use of `TextCtrl` in your sample with one of those widgets, and replace `SetValue` with `SetPage` and it should work the way you want. See the docs for specifics and give it a try.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Works perfectly. Can't now see why I had a problem